# PowerBI - Convert text to time

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am working with a set of data called Response time and it is currently in the format of hh:mm:ss but the field is a text field in Power BI Power Query Editor.  I am trying to convert it to straight time so I can get an average from it but I keep getting errors due to many of the times being higher than 24 hours. I have results of like 37:50:00 and 40:00:00 and those error out while times like 22:24:00 work fine but it is converted to the actual time on a clock.

How do I keep the design of the data but get it into a Time data type so that I can pull an average?

Comment: You can't use the time type as it will display time, not a length of time, it needs to be the duration datatype

Comment: Which duration do I use though?  I have tried a couple of the built-in ones and anything over 24 hours errors out.

Comment: So some additional info on this.  I have hours in one column and minutes in a separate column.  I created a custom column and here is the code I am using:

Comment: Where is "here"? Please edit your question to post more details. Comments are not meant to be used for code

Comment: Sorry, hit save before I pasted.  Here is the code I am using to create the new column:

So some additional info on this.  I have hours in one column and minutes in a separate column.  I created a custom column and here is the code I am using:

ResolvedTime = Text.From([RHour2] & ":" & [RMin2] & ":00") and this gives me values